# Logitech MX Master 2S Configure Horizontal (Side) Scroll and Thumb Button Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mouse, logitech, mouse-scroll

Any ideas on how to make the Logitech MX Master 2S mouse thumb button to show desktop and the horizontal scroll to be zoom in/out?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: What do you mean with zoom in/out? For me thumb button works to switch desktop (gestures) or show open windows (simple press) with the following approach: https://askubuntu.com/a/1246278/678626